# Find out when your index was last rebuilt / reorganized

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, index-tuning, fragmentation

I've recently come across a database, which has very high fragmentation on large tables.

Page count > 1'000'000 with fragmentation 99,...

I would like to know how long this table has gone without a reorganize / rebuild. 
That way I can review changes made on that date, to try and find a cause. (Also it'd look nice on my report "this database has not been properly maintained since...)

As I'm in the process of setting up a job to quickly reorganize the affected tables (this night probably), any solution that could offer me a history of index operations would be much appreciated. If not, simply knowing that I can check this data in the future would be very helpful.

Comment: Possibly duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2831293/tsql-know-when-index-rebuild-reorg-or-updatestatistics-was-last-run-on-sql-ser

Comment: @Shanky In regards to the possibly duplicate remark. I did come across that post in my own research into the question, but as it offered no real answer and is 4+ years old. I was hoping someone might have an answer by now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SQL Server does not maintain when an Index was last rebuild, instead it keeps information when stats were last updated.

That can be found using the `STATS_DATE` function.

You can use [Ola's Index maintenance solution](https://ola.hallengren.com/sql-server-index-and-statistics-maintenance.html) or [Michelle Ufford's - Index Defrag Script](http://sqlfool.com/2010/04/index-defrag-script-v4-0/). These scripts are widely tested in the community and are much flexible so that you can adapt as per your needs in your environment.

SQL Server  SP2 for 2008R2 and up has a new DMF [`sys.dm_db_stats_properties`](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/erin/new-statistics-dmf-in-sql-server-2008r2-sp2/) which tells you when your stats were last updated with other info like

> modification_counter: number of modifications for the column which leads the statistic, since the last update

Comment: I was already using Ola's script to create maintenance plans. However they don't give me the information I'm looking for right now. I'll try looking at the sys.dm_db_stats_properties to see what I can glean there. However I believe auto update statistics is on, which means they will be updated frequently regardless of index operations I believe.

Comment: But this is not a solution you cannot for sure tell looking at time when stats was last rebuild. Because if you manually update stats date would change but that is surely not date when index was rebuilt.

Comment: @Shanky Which is what I ment when I said that they will be updated frequently regardless of index operations ;)

Comment: There is no other way, unless you are logging the index rebuilds in a table. This is what I do in my environment. Ola's script offers that flexiblity of loggin into a table with `@LogToTable = 'Y'`. Then you can use that info and see what indexes are having bad fragmentation and requires a rebuilt.

Comment: @Kin I'm not immediately willing to take "not possible" as answer just yet. I'll keep looking for a while (time permitting) and might update here if I find an answer. As such I'm not immediately accepting your answer hoping someone might have a way after all.

Answer (score 2):

As Kin noted above, it is not possible to get this information since it is not stored by SQL Server.  Please refer [to this article on technet](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/18767.how-to-check-when-index-was-last-rebuilt.aspx).  Since you are using Ola's scripts, unless you changed the defaults, the output of the IndexOptimize job should go to the same location as your error log.

Comment: In this particular case I came into a database not under my management (yet). This means the database did not yet have decent maintenance set up, let alone logging of maintenance tasks.

Comment: @Reaces In that case, I would worry more about getting all the maintenance jobs run. Knowing when it was last rebuilt isn't going to help you except to place blame.  In my experience, if there was no formal maintenance set up it is usually safe to assume that none was ever done. If there was a maintenance plan or other jobs then you should be able to check the job history/msdb.

Comment: I agree. Get it taken care of now, and then keep an eye on it to determine how fast it gets fragmented. You may be able to use that to extrapolate back to a rough period of time if you know enough about the environment(and are reporting to people who won't know any better).

Comment: @Your_comment_is_not_funny I have already taken care of the indexes in question, and set up a maintenance plan. (With daily / weekly / offline window parts) Now it's mostly a matter of finding out what broke and removing it. I don't want to risk two plans running cross purposes.